# Replacing resistances with equivalent resistance

Tags: circuit-analysis, parallel, nodal-analysis, equivalent-circuit

[image]

In the above original circuit,by node analysis,we see that \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$ are in parallel combination. So we can replace the two with an equivalent resistance \$R_e\$. For that we need to remove the two resistances and use only a single resistance \$R_e\$ in between the two nodes. In the figure below,two equivalent circuits are drawn where the new resistance is \$R_p\$ in the first one and \$R_p'\$ in the second one.

According to the books,the first one is correct. But I want to know why we are placing \$R_p\$ in the place of \$R_3\$. Why aren't we placing \$R_p\$ in \$R_4\$'s wire just like in the second circuit?

In case of removing such resistances in parallel,how can we understand *which resistances and wires to what extent can be erased*? This issue is creating troubles for me in doing circuit analysis.

Comment: Tip: use `\$` for inline MathJAX on this site. It's `$` on most of the other sites but we don't understand how they manage to discuss cost! I fixed your post.

Comment: @Transistor In my experience, although electronic components can be obtained at reasonable prices, mathematical components are usually so cheap that the cost is not worth discussing! I got a box of 10,000 cosines from a friend for free over a decade ago, and I haven't even used half of them yet.

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpjKaO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Circuit redrawn for clarity.*

- It should be clear from the equivalent circuit in Figure 1 that R3 and R4 are in parallel as you have correctly figured out.
- It should now also be clear that R2 and R5 are in parallel so they too can be combined using the parallel resistor calculation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuY39W.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Parallelling the resistors.*

- Now in Figure 2 it becomes clear that R1 is in series with the R2 || R5 combination so we can add those.
- You will then be left with (R3 || R4) || (R1 + (R2 || R5)) which can again be solved with the parallel resistor rule.

Summary:

- You can parallel resistors that share the same nodes.
- You can series resistors that share one node but have no alternate current branches.